# C# HttpListener Class not Working with Windows 10 version 1803

Tags: c#, smb, httplistener

I am installing software on a Windows 10 machine with a fresh install of update 1803 which uses the C# `HttpListener` class as web-server. This software has worked on every version of Windows since XP. However on 1803, I cannot connect to the web server suddenly. If I run the software as an Administrator (which I have never had to do before), I can connect on `localhost` only, but not from another machine on the network.

I have been through all the articles on networking with version 1803 and sharing and turning on SMB version 1, but none of that has handled the problem. I am baffled at the moment.

This is the server code:

```
internal WebServer(RuntimeDB database)
{
    _db = database;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 1000);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(5, 50);
    _listener = new HttpListener {IgnoreWriteExceptions = true};
    _listener.Prefixes.Add("https://+:443/secure/");
    _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/trigger/");
}

internal void Start()
{
    try {
        _listener.Start();
        while (_listener.IsListening) {
            try {
                var request = _listener.GetContext();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessRequest, request);
            } catch (HttpListenerException) {
                break;
            } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogMsg($"Fatal Error on thread WebServer: {e.Message}. Source: {e.Source} Target Site: {e.TargetSite}  Stack Trace: {e.StackTrace}");
    } finally {
        _listener?.Stop();
        _listener?.Close();
    }
}
```

This works fine on the previous version of Windows 10, so I am assuming there is some change in the networking stack or something. No exceptions are being generated by the code. Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `c#`. Check your firewall settings or something. Also I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Does the same thing with firewall off, so does not seem to be a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable listening on the specific ports by using the netsh-command.

```
netsh add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=DOMAIN\user listen=yes
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl) for more info

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have the firewall ports open and have also tried shutting down the firewall entirely. I cannot access the webserver even using https://localhost/secure/ unless I run the web server as an Administrator.

Comment: @SteveMyers Did you try the command i've mentioned, if not you should.

Comment: OK, you are right. I needed to use this command and I found out that it must EXACTLY match the URL I have specified for HttpListener. Otherwise, I get an access denied error. Thanks!